# Can we write a Spring Batch Job Without ItemReader and ItemWriter

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In my project, I have written a Quartz scheduler with Spring Batch 2.2.

As per my requirement, I want to run a scheduler to fetch application config property to refresh the configuration cache on all the GlassFish Clusters.

So I dont need ItemWriter and ItemReader which are used to for File Read/Write operations.
So can I remove **ItemReader** and **ItemWriter** from  ?

The configuration of my job is mentioned below :

```
 <batch:job id="reportJob">
                 <batch:step id="step1">
                     <batch:tasklet>    
    <!--I want to remove ItemReader and ItemWriter as its not used -->          
                         <batch:chunk reader="ItemReader" writer="ItemWriter" 
                            commit-interval="10"> 
                        </batch:chunk> 
                    </batch:tasklet> 
                </batch:step> 

                <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="simpleListener"/>
                </batch:listeners>
            </batch:job>

<bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
            <!-- Cache Refresh code is written here : JobLauncherDetails.java file -->
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.mkyong.quartz.JobLauncherDetails" />
        <property name="group" value="quartz-batch" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="jobName" value="reportJob" />
                <entry key="jobLocator" value-ref="jobRegistry" />
                <entry key="jobLauncher" value-ref="jobLauncher" />
                <entry key="param1" value="mkyong1" />
                <entry key="param2" value="mkyong2" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I writing my business logic to refresh cache on JobClass JobLauncherDetails.java.
So is it possible to remove ItemReader and ItemWriter ? Do we have any possible alternative way ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a [Tasklet](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html)

```
<job id="reportJob">
  <step id="step1">
    <tasklet ref="MyTaskletBean" />
  </step>
  <!-- Other config... -->
</job> 



class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {
  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
  }
}
```

You can read more on Tasklet at chapter 5.2 from [official doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply bellabax. It creation of new Tasklet bean worked for me.

Comment: But I have seen somewhere that for ItemReader, ItemProcessor and ItemProcessor, we can defined three seperate steps like .. step1 will read the file, step2 will process the file and step3 will write the file. so we dont need to create tasklet and chunks. Fow year back I have seen the same type of development somewhere in spring. Let me if it is possible ? can we remove tasklet and chunk and write thee separate steps for itemreading,itemprocessing and itemwriting ?

Comment: I don't think so because a reader and a writer are mandatory (as well as one between completion-policy and commit-interval)

Comment: Okie .. it may be some older version of Spring Batch or something else..thanks