# Spring Batch delete rows from database

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I am writing a job to delete a large of rows from database

```
<job id="clean-data-except-90009" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

    <step id="clean-data">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="abc" writer="cleanDataVendPoWriter" 
            commit-interval="100" skip-limit="100" retry-limit="50">
                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException" />
                </skippable-exception-classes>
                <retryable-exception-classes>
                    <include
                        class="org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException" />
                </retryable-exception-classes>
            </chunk>
            <no-rollback-exception-classes>
                <include class="org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException" />
            </no-rollback-exception-classes>
        </tasklet>
        <!-- <next on="COMPLETED" to="get-order-delete"/>  -->
    </step>
```

And here is writer:

```
<bean id="cleanDataVendPoWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql" value="${coms.dsv.sql.deleteVenPo}" />
</bean>
```

I don't know to put anything into "reader", I just want to delete rows in a table of database and not reading data from anywhere.
If I remove reader in chunk, it will error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680648/can-we-write-a-spring-batch-job-without-itemreader-and-itemwriter/22680927#22680927 for a possible solution

Comment: Thank for your suggestion! But I don't know how to set commit-interval for tasklet

Comment: A tasklet can't have a commit-interval. just delete all rows. I can't see any gain having a chunk processing for you job. And how can you get a `DuplicateKeyException` on a delete operation?