# Spring batch jobs - How to skip reader and processor part?

Tags: java, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am developing a **Spring batch job** , in which there is no requirement of Reader and Processor. All I need is a writer to insert and delete records from Database.How Reader and Processor can be skipped? Creating a **Tasklet** could be one of the options?
What are the other ways to do it ,If i don't want to use **Tasklet**..!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we write a Spring Batch Job Without ItemReader and ItemWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680648/can-we-write-a-spring-batch-job-without-itemreader-and-itemwriter)

Comment: @Luca Thanks for suggestion. but I am looking for other ways to do it ,Is it possible to do it without using Tasklets...

Comment: With given specification is impossible to me (us) give you a better answer. Please be more specifi about your use case or use a Tasklet (or don't use SB)

Comment: @Luca  I did it using Tasklets. just wanted to know if there are any other options. Anyway thanks a lot :)