# How to skip exception thrown in a method annotated with @BeforeStep

Tags: spring-batch

I am using chunk Reader, Processor and Writer pattern to process our data. The approach i took is, before going to Reader's read method, i run a sql which connects to db and pulls all the required data. This is done in a method annotated with @BeforeStep and the output data becomes the source for the Reader's read method which iterates through this generated data and retrieves an item per read for processor. Any exception thrown during the flow is caught and retried using the @Retryable feature and skipped using the skippable exception feature.

One thing that is confusing for me is, any exception that is thrown in the method annotated with @BeforeStep is caught and a custom skippable exception is thrown by the app which isn't getting skipped by the system. Is this the desired behavior or am i missing something. Please help me in this.

Thanks,
raveendra

Comment: Are the specific reasons to pull data in @BeforeStep and not using a SQL based ItemReader directly?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci - This is as per the design. We want to open a connection, run a big sql to fetch the data and work on the retrieved data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If design force you to pull data from DB a reasonable solution is to create a step before the main one and move code from @BeforeStep into this new step; you can manage skippable-exception and retry condition better than in a listener.

You can look at this answer ([Can we write a Spring Batch Job Without ItemReader and ItemWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680648/can-we-write-a-spring-batch-job-without-itemreader-and-itemwriter/22680927#22680927)); in `Tasklet#execute()` write something like:

```
class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {
 @Override
 public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
  // Fetch data using JdbcTemplate (for example) and pull to external bean to let extracted data visible to next step
  return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
 }
}
```

Also check SO for 'passing data between steps spring batch' for extra info

Comment: @ LucaBassoRicci - This sounds as an option. I am trying to understand, is there any support for such a case by the platform.